# How much more damage is caused after hitting a brick wall at 100mph over 50mph?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, momentum, collision

How much more damage is caused after hitting a wall at 100mph over 50mph? It is clear that there is just twice as much force generated after hitting a wall at 100mph, since the deacceleration is twice as large. But is the energy produced four times as much? This is unclear to me.

Comment: Why is the deceleration twice as large?

Comment: What is hitting the wall? A simple brick wall won't yield to your fist, but an automobile that hits one at 50 miles per hour probably will not stop until some distance beyond the place where the wall used to be. Maybe you meant to ask about a sheer granite cliff face?